# Locating cordova.2.3.0.jar file?

Tags: android, cordova

Where can I find the cordova.2.0.3.jar ? I am trying to get running with PhoneGap on android.

```
localhost:bin shuttle$ ./create ~/Documents/cordova-android/HelloWorld com.Name.HelloWorld HelloWorld
cp: /Users/shuttle/Documents/cordova-android/framework/cordova-2.3.0.jar: No such file or directory
An unexpected error occurred: cp "$BUILD_PATH"/framework/cordova-$VERSION.jar "$PROJECT_PATH"/libs/cordova-$VERSION.jar exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link .Download Phonegap and check whether it is  cordova.2.0.3. If you are using android then open phonegap which you downloaded (phonegap/libs/android/(cordova.jar and cordova.js) or (phonegap.jar and phonegap.js). Then copy that cordova.jar and paste in android project (android project/libs/cordova.jar) and copy that cordova.js and paste in same android project(android project/assets/www/cordova.js). In this link you can easily understand phonegap tutorials and you can get some idea over it.....

http://phonegap.com/download/